# Why is prediction of the length of a salmon based on (or as a function of) its age and weight a regression problem?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, classification, supervised-learning

When we try to predict the length of a salmon based on its age and weight, here the age and weight are features. And length is the class, that is - a numerical class instead of textual class.

So we can train a model given various combinations of age, weight and the corresponding length.

Why is prediction of the length of a salmon based on (or as a function of) its age and weight a regression problem?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what your features are, but what you predict.

You can always convert a regression problem into a classification problem. Just put your outputs into a fixed number of bins, e.g. *"Class A: length between 70cm and 1m"*, etc.

If you do classification with many bins instead you waste precious training data to learn something you already know: that bins of similar length should get similar predictions.

Comment: Agree with your class approach. But, any how, effectively each length value is like a class. Example: If I consider every value from 0.00 to 50.00 as a class. Then does it become a classification problem? (instead of a regression problem?)

Comment: Given enough data, you can solve this problem with a classification method and 5'000 classes. Doing that doesn't change the problem. *Salmon length* is still a number without discrete steps and not a category.

Answer (score 0):

Predicting the length of a salmon can be framed as a regression problem because

- The set of possible outputs is unbounded.<sup>1</sup>
- There is no way to enumerate all possible outcomes.
- This also implies that the set of possible predictions is not known at training time.

This is quite different from a classification problem where the set of possible outputs is fixed, known at training time and where it is possible to enumerate them.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Actually, in the case of fish length a length smaller than `0.0` is not feasible, but in the positive domain, outputs are unbounded.</sub>

Comment: Assuming there is an upper bound of say 50, then does it become a classification problem? So this way, every possible length value from 0.00 to 50.00 becomes a class. So it becomes a bounded problem. And so can be called classification instead of regression?

Comment: @variable No, a bound on its own does not make it classification. The set of all possible predictions must also be enumerable. That's not the case with an upper bound of `50.0` - there are infinitely many float numbers between 0.0 and 50.0. I edited the answer to make it more clear.